# How to insert app settings from web.config into a view template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-config

This is my `web.config` code

```
<add key="SiteLogoPath" value="#SiteLogoPath#" />
```

This is my Template code

```
<p>#SiteLogoPath#</p>
```

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your question really boils down to inserting an app setting into a Razor template:

In `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SiteLogoPath" value="#SiteLogoPath#" />
</appSettings>
```

In your Razor template:

```
@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteLogoPath"]
```